# Complex/Compund sentence to simple Spacy

Tags: computational-linguistics

I want to use Spacy and Python and convert a sentence to simple one irrespective being a complex or a compound sentence.

Comment: Sorry but we don't generally provide programming support here.

Comment: @curiousdannii It's still on-topic here.

Comment: @prash The question is also not anywhere near specific enough about what kind of "conversion" is desired to give any helpful advice.

Comment: @Ashna you need to be clearer about the degree of granularity you're looking for. It's pretty easy to prune optional branches from a parse tree and then generate a sentence out of it.

Comment: @curiousdannii Noted. I was typing her some hints :-)